# Словообразовательный разбор

Tags: словообразование

От какого слова образовано слово перелетный. Нужно провести словообразовательный разбор

Answer (score 3):

Начинаем с определения.

Перелётная птица - птица, которая совершает перелёт.

Перелетный - от сущ. перелёт с помощью суфф.-Н--суффиксальный способ.

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, что ПЕРЕЛЁТНЫЙ - это тот, который перелетел (от глагола "перелететь"). Далее происходит усечение основы(- е): перелет - е - ть и добавляется суффикс -Н-. Таким образом, это тоже суффиксальный способ, но от глагола.

Answer (score 0):

С самого начала (кратко):

- Лёт (сущ. движение по воздуху)
- Летать (гл. двигаться по воздуху)
- Перелететь (гл. совершить движение из одной точки в другую, совершить движение через препятствие)
- Перелетный (прил. совершивший движение из одной точки в другую, совершивший движение через препятствие)

Таким образом получаем слово с помощью суффикса и приставки.